# Creating a function with column name in group_by clause

Tags: r, function, group-by

I am trying to specify a following function where I wall pass a dataset's column name as a name to group_by clause.

```
counter<-function(df,col_name){
      a<-df %>% 
      group_by(col_name) %>% 
      count() %>% 
      arrange(desc(n))
  return(a)
}
```

So if I try for example:

```
fraud_continent<-counter(fraud,continent_source1)
```

where fraud is dataset and continent_source1 is the column name from this dataset, the function wont work and the error I get is:

Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.

- Column `col_name` is not found.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curly curly operator (`{{}}`).

```
counter<-function(df,col_name){
  a<-df %>% 
    group_by({{col_name}}) %>% 
    count() %>% 
    arrange(desc(n))
  return(a)
}
```

Also you can do this without `group_by` -

```
counter<-function(df,col_name){
  a<-df %>% 
    count({{col_name}}) %>% 
    arrange(desc(n))
  return(a)
}
```

This can be called as -

```
fraud_continent<-counter(fraud,continent_source1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Update:
Thanks to the support of akrun `.data[[col_name]]` is better:

First answer:
Or you could use `df[,col_name]`

```
library(dplyr)
counter<-function(df,col_name){
    a<-df %>% 
        group_by(df[,col_name]) %>% 
        count() %>% 
        arrange(desc(n))
    return(a)
}

fraud_continent<-counter(fraud,"continent_source1")
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use `ensym` with `!!`

```
library(dplyr)
counter <- function(df, colname){
     df %>%
      count(!! rlang::ensym(colname)) %>%
      arrange(desc(n))
}
```

and then it can be called as either

```
fraud_continent<-counter(fraud,continent_source1)
```

Or

```
fraud_continent<-counter(fraud, "continent_source1")
```